# Result not showing as I want to (C++ code)

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I'm a novice in C++ so don't really know much but I want to learn and practice. I've written a code where the user will state how many persons he/she wants to write the names, and the names will be in char. I will then have to sort this using insertion to see which name is well sorted Alphabetically.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Name{
public:
    void sortInsertion(int, char* );

};
void Name::sortInsertion(int size, char *c){
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++){
        int j;
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && c[j] < c[j - 1]){
            swap(c[j], c[j - 1]);
            j = j - 1;
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    Name n;
    char* name;
    name = new char[30];
    int* in;

    int size = 0;
    in = new int[size];
    cout << "How many people?: ";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << "Person " << i+1 <<": "<< endl;
        cout << "Full Name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(name,29);
        cout << endl;
    }
    n.sortInsertion(size, name);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << "Person " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cout << "Full Name: ";
        cout << name << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

this is my code. It doesn't show the result as I want it to show, the output misses the first letter of the name and only repeats the printing of the last user input given. 
Could you please tell me what's wrong? Any help and tip is really appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what's going on ?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++){` indexing in c++ starts at `0`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That loop isn't obviously wrong. It's accessing `c[i]` and `c[i-1]` to inspect every pair from beginning to end.

Comment: What is the point of the variable `in`?

Comment: Why did you create a `struct` with only a function in it?  You could make your program simpler by extracting the function from the structure as a standalone function.  Another trick would be to place the function in a separate namespace.

Comment: Change `name` from an array of characters to an array of `std::string`.  Better, prefer to use `std::vector<std::string>>`.  If you **used a debugger** you would notice that your input loop is replacing the C-Style string in `name` each time.  You are not storing *all* the names, only the last one.

Comment: Also, your `sortInsertion` function is sorting the *letters* in the C-Style string.  You should study up on the difference between a character array (C-Style string) and an array of C-Style strings.  To avoid this confusion, use `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Comment: I will take in everyone's advice to see what my debugger shows step by step. I will try to research the differences between char array and c-style string arrays. Also @ThomasMatthews I had to use a class as a requirement for my assignment. 
I know it's a lot easier to do with strings but I have to use char as a prerequisite for the assignment